# Blender to unity - object is offset

Tags: game-engine, unity

Ok, so basically I made a 3d model using blender, and I imported it into unity by right clicking -> import asset -> 3dModel.blend.

It looks fine and all, but if I try to move the object, the object is far away from the thing that moves it.
Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

As a result, the asset would rotate in a BIG circle.

So... How do I revert this to a normal state? (Like this one)

[image: image2]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know a lot about Unity, but in Blender, is your pivot point located in the center of your object?

Comment: How do I know this?
Because I am new to blender :)

Comment: When you select your object in Blender, there will be a small orange dot somewhere. This is your origin point. Your origin is probably not centered in the object you're exporting.

Comment: Hm... there is no orange dot anymore.
What do I do?

Comment: Right click on your object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry. Check if you can see it after doing that.